# Android Firebase Notifications - Notify users to comment reply

Tags: android, firebase

Im trying to create a feature on an app where users can be notified that someone replied to something they posted.

So far i have setup Firebase Notifications so i can send notifications from the firebase dashboard to an individual device, a group subscribed to a topic etc..

How do i add a feature that when a registered user posts something that fits a criteria it will post it to the group and the subscribed users will be notified.

I assume it just need to be able to allow users to post to certain "topics" and firebase will send the notifications but how do i allow a user to post directly to a topic from the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a Firebase cloud function on the Realtime Database location using wildcards and this function can then call the Firebase cloud messaging REST api with Topic/Regid that you want.

Check out more about Firebase Cloud functions:

https://firebase.google.com/products/functions/

Alternatively, you can do this from the client side as well.... Basically if someone posts something under a Location in RDB, Call the Firebase Cloud Messaging Rest api for the creator of the node. I would suggest subscribing each user to a Topic which is their own userid. This way, when anyone posts, you can send a FCM push to this userid topic.

Comment: Im getting close now. Im getting a success 200 message but the message isnt being recieved on the device thats subscribed. Even though when i go to the console and send message manually it goes to device subscribed to "news"

Comment: you'll have to update the code that you've made for me to check buddy. I don't know what you've tried currently